# How do i get rid of the new line on the last line of output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`print("testing... \n" * 3)` on the \n aria, how do i stop the output being:

output:

```
testing...
testing...
testing...
```

and then a new line.
how to stop plz? I am trying to do tutorial.

Comment: If you use `'\n'.join(...)` it will put the newline only between items. `print("\n".join(["testing"]*3))`

Comment: Or, add `end=""` to suppress the newline `print()` normally produces.